# Notification doesn't vibrate

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

```
const val channelId = "notification_channel"
const val channelName = "com.deskmateai.t2chaiwala"
val vibration = longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200)

class MyFirebaseMessagingService: FirebaseMessagingService() {
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
    generateNotification(remoteMessage.notification!!.title!!, remoteMessage.notification!!.body!!)

}

// generating notification
private fun generateNotification(title: String, description: String){
    val builder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, channelId)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tea_notify_logo)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentText(description)
        .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
        .setVibrate(longArrayOf(500, 500))
    val v = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    v.vibrate(1000)
    val manager: NotificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)
    manager.notify(1, builder.build())

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        channel.enableLights(true)
        channel.enableVibration(true)
        channel.vibrationPattern = vibration

        val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        manager.notify(1, builder.build())
    }

}
```

I am making an app in android for that i have integrated firebaase push notification, but my hone is not vibrating when notification come .
I have also added vibration permission in android manifest file. and as you can see in code i have done everything to vibrate my phone on notification but it is not.

Comment: If the ``Vibrator`` instance isn't working either, then it's not an issue with notifications. Check your device isn't on silent, Do Not Disturb or anything like that. Some phones disable things by default, and you have to enable them per-app in the settings, so I'd look into that too. Also try restarting your phone, just in case the vibrator isn't working (it happens sometimes, like when the haptics on keyboard presses disappear)

Comment: It is not working in any of phone. I have tested it in more than 6 devices

Comment: You could try the ``vibrate`` call that takes a ``VibrationEffect`` (which you're supposed to be using in *API 26+*) but it should be as simple as *add VIBRATE permission, get Vibrator service, call ``vibrate``*. That's all I had to do in a similar situation

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the vibration when you are creating the channel. Also, make sure to reinstall your app to apply channel changes.

```
private fun createCallNotificationChannel(): NotificationChannelCompat {
        val channel = NotificationChannelCompat.Builder(
            INCOMING_CALL_CHANNEL_ID,
            NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        ).setName("Incoming notification")
            .setDescription("Incoming notification alerts")
            .setVibrationEnabled(true)
            .build()
        return channel
    }
```